# Is there easy way to replace .Wait() to be able to handle it asynchronously

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-4.5

I have small console app and I'm having problem making the app wait for all process to finish before closing. Since this is something that will to run on schedule, I can not simply add `Console.ReadKey` or something of that sort.

When calling my first Async method, I had to add `.Wait();`  to prevent app from proceeding with the rest of the code. I'm trying to understand if this is acceptable way to do it in console application or is there better way (hopefully simple) to ensure that application waits on async method before closing. Additionally I'm want to be able to reduce amount of resources that application consumes, and my understanding that `.Wait()` will tie up that thread instead of releasing it, that will lead to extra resource usage.

Below is how my logic laid out.

```
private static List<string> taskList = new List<string>();
private static SemaphoreSlim mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(3);

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartAllTasks().Wait(); // This LINE 
}

private static async Task StartAllTasks()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(taskList.Select(name => ProcessSingleTask(name)));
}

private async static Task ProcessSingleTask(string name)
{
    await mutex.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        TaskManager singleTask = new TaskManager(name);
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => singleTask.ProcessTask());
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.Release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, what you have is the optimal way(in this context). In fact this is the recommended way to wait for a `Task` inside the `Main` method.  Main method can't be `async` and thus you can't `await` inside the Main.

Other common options are waiting on a `WaitHandle` till someone says it's time to shutdown, that is effectively same as what you have. So stick with it.

If you're talking about other methods, that's a different story. But for `Main` this is perfectly alright.

Answer (score 1):

`Wait` is acceptable in a console's `Main`. It will "waste" a thread, but wasting a single thread is usually not that big of a deal.

If it bothers you, you could use [`AsyncContext` from my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) which will actually provide a single-threaded context for the `async` code. It will also not wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`. However, this means your `async` code won't execute on thread pool threads - it will all execute on the single console main thread.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done looks correct. You need the call to Wait() to block the main thread since that is keeping your program alive. Blocking a thread does not mean using up too many resources though.

The wait and await calls are not doing anything that is hurting the CPU, although they do necessarily block threads.

Threads are also quite lightweight so don't worry too much!

Comment: Not agree. We should always be thinking about consumption of resources, and threads ARE limited resources. Here we have to `Wait` somehow, but in general we should be carefull not to consume a thread just to synchronously wait for some results. For example, because of that we can consume thread pool much faster in ASP.NET under heavy load.

Comment: As I said in my answer, "don't worry too much". Just using a thread does not equal bad. The code shown is not using lots of threads to wait so it is the correct way and he should not worry.